# Different confidence interval between R and SPSS results

Tags: r, spss

I have a small dataset with the total number of cases under 20. 
When I ran survival analysis using Kaplan-Meier estimate on SPSS with this dataset, I was able to get specific 95% upper and lower confidence interval values, but in R (using survfit, conf.type "log-log") 0.95UCL is not estimated. I get the feeling that this happens often when I get to use small datasets. 
I'm not sure if it's accurate but I've read that SPSS provides log-log as default. So, could anyone let me know why the result is like this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like there is `lower` and `upper` in `survfit` output, see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.11. -4/topics/summary.survfit). Is this what you need?. `conf.int` parameter controls the level but defaults to 0.95 which you need

Comment: @JonnyPhelps I tried summary(survfit) and it seems like that it provides 95% confidence interval for each events in survival table.
Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the confidence intervals in SPSS KM are equivalent to the "plain" option in R's survfit, not the "log-log" option. You can see the formulas in the KM chapter of the [IBM SPSS Statistics Algorithms manual](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/26.0/en/client/Manuals/IBM_SPSS_Statistics_Algorithms.pdf).